# Calculate $\int_0^1 \frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x} d x$ without $\zeta(2)$.

Tags: definite-integrals

Can we calculate the following integral without the need of $\zeta(2)$, I actually believe that this can be a method to find the accurate value of $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-2}$.

$$\int_0^1 -\frac{\log (1-x)}{x} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

---

Any help is appreciated , just act as you do not know that the sum of reciprocal of squares equal $ \frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

I hope this topic is not duplicated.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you *specifically* do not want the solution that expresses the function under the integral as a power series, then integrates the summands and finally uses the formula for $\sum_n n^{-2}$ ?

Comment: If you don't want Riemann's Zeta function, how about Polylogarithm? :)

Comment: @Feanor : Yes, I already know that solution, are there any other solutions ?

Comment: @Kaster : I know that the indefinite integral is $\text{Li}_2(x)$, but the only thing a could get from this is that the integral equals the sum of reciprocal of squares (i.e $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^{-2}$) which I can use it in this case (I said just act like you don't know this sum), do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^1-\frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}\,dx=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xy}\,dy\,dx$$

Now got to page 10 of [this article.](http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/MathGradTalkZeta2.pdf)